# Parsimonious ParseError

Tags: python, parsing, parsimonious

Digging deeper into grammars and PEG in special, I wanted to have a DSL with the following syntax:

```
a OR (b AND c)
```

I am using **[`parsimonious`](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious)** here with the following grammar:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
grammar = Grammar(
    """
    expr            = (term operator term)+
    term            = (lpar term rpar) / (variable operator variable)
    operator        = and / or
    or              = _? "OR" _?
    and             = _? "AND" _?
    variable        = ~r"[a-z]+"
    lpar            = "("
    rpar            = ")"
    _               = ~r"\s*"
    """
)
print(grammar.parse('a OR (b AND c)'))
```

However, this fails for the above text with

```
parsimonious.exceptions.ParseError: Rule 'variable' didn't match at '(b AND c)' (line 1, column 6).
```

Why? Haven't I specified `term` as `( term )` or `term` ?
Why does it choose the rule for `variable` instead (which of course fails) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing in `expr` is a `term`, so that's what the parser looks for.

A `term` in your grammar is either

```
( term )
```

or

```
variable operator variable
```

And the input is

```
a OR (b AND c)
```

That doesn't start with a `(` so the only way it can be a `term` is if it matches `variable operator variable`. `a` is a `variable`; `OR` is an `operator`. So the next thing to match is `variable`.

---

Perhaps what you want is:

```
expr = term (operator term)*
term = (lpar expr rpar) / variable
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, very appreciated.